# What's the difference between `require` and `gem`

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What's the difference between `require 'cool_lib'` and `gem 'cool_lib'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gem` gives you more options as to which exact gem you load: [see here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4) for plenty of details. In this example, there's no effective difference.

I'd recommend using `require` unless you specifically need the power of `gem` - it seems to be what most people use.

Comment: One difference is that if you are sharing your code with someone who doesn't use rubygems, the 'require' form will still work for them (as long as they have manually installed cool_lib in the include path).

Comment: Good answer, but don't "require 'rubygems'".  See: http://www.rubyinside.com/why-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html .

Comment: @Wayne: I've removed the `require 'rubygems'`; fair point. I mainly said it since it's an easy 'gotcha' for new players.

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but if `require 'rubygems'` is wrong, is it wrong to use `gem`?